# Episerver CMS form "Multiple or single choice"

Tags: content-management-system, episerver

Episerver CMS form "Multiple or single choice" when the field is required. The asterisk is displaying on the options.

Is there a way that the asterisk(*) should be after question, not the options?
[See Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qd76.png)

Comment: Are you using default rendering? Could you also post a screenshot of your form field settings?

Comment: @TedNyberg here's the screenshot link(s). 

https://i.imgur.com/xIF3vJp.png

Output render

https://i.imgur.com/AFoRRDC.png

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using default rendering for all Episerver Forms elements?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the asterixes in your picture have been put there manually. Simply rewrite your labels

[image]

This will render your forms like this (the example is with a customized template)

[image]

Comment: Hi,

I did try and follow your steps, unfortunately, the output still the same.

https://i.imgur.com/xIF3vJp.png

Output render

https://i.imgur.com/AFoRRDC.png

Comment: @NezaMelencion In that case you are adding that styling or have modified the form fields implementation. The default behaviour does not add the asterisk, at least not to my knowledge. So check your styling.

Comment: Hi @Eric and @TedNyberg I just did some js hack and it works well. Thank you guys for the responses, appreciate a lot. e.g.

`checkRequiredRadioButton: function () {
        var form = $(".EpiForms-body > section .Form__Element.FormChoice.ValidationRequired");

        form.find(".Form__Element__Caption").each(function () {
            form.addClass('NoAfter');
            form.addClass('LegendValidationRequired');
        });
    }`